# Parse a simple text file with dos cmd line

Tags: parsing, batch-file, cmd

I have a text file (vernum.txt) containing one line:

> At revision 2.

How do I use dos cmd line to read in the line and save a variable with JUST the number?  It will always be "At Revision ####."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a command such as this:

```
@ECHO off

SET /P MYVAR=<vernum.txt
ECHO MYVAR=%MYVAR%
FOR /f "tokens=3* delims=.\ " %%K IN ( "%MYVAR%" ) DO (
    SET /A RESULT=%%K
)
ECHO The number is: %RESULT%

pause
```

Comment: Hello, Im new to dos cmd line and I need a very similar solution. Im parsing a larger file and trying to pull out a different number. Would you mind quickly explaining your code. Mainly the for loop so I can understand it and edit it for me needs. @djangofan

Answer (score 3):

```
for /f "tokens=3delims=. " %%i in (vernum.txt) do set vernum=%%i

echo version number=%vernum%
```

You may need to change `vernum.txt` to the full pathname if the file is not in the current directory. If your filename contains spaces, the name needs to be quoted using "double quotes". If you use quotes, you'd also need to add the key directive `usebackq` into the quote before the `tokens` keyword

The space before the closing quote in the qualifier is significant - it means "delimiters are `.` or `space`. The `tokens=3` means the third token : `At`  `revision` and `2`

See `for /?` from the prompt for documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately, that answer fails since it returns "3." rather than "3"